# Rotation on the coordinate plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*This question was taken from Khan Academy's Prealculus section*
[image]

My main issue here is figuring out the right plan of attack for this type of question. This is how I went about it.

1) I found the midpoints of both lines, $AB$ and $MN$ which happened to be $(1.5, -2.5)$ and $(-1.5, 3.5)$, respectively.

2) Then using the two given points of each line I found the equations of the lines. 
$AB$ was $y=-3 x+2$ and $MN$ was $y=-\frac { 1 }{ 5 } x+\frac { 16 }{ 5 } $

3) Next I found the perpendicular bisectors of both lines by using their midpoints. These came out to be $y=\frac { 1 }{ 3 } x-3$ and $y=5x+11$

4) Then I calculated the point where these two lines intersect each other by setting both equations equal to each other and this point equaled to $(-3,-4)$

Now I am not sure whether or not I am going about this the right way and how to get the coordinates of the point he gave under the $90$ degree rotation

Comment: are you sure that center you located is correct

Comment: Yes, but the New Point that I entered (as you can see in the picture) was wrong. Thankfully, I caught that mistake before I submitted the question

Comment: I have answered your question you can have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methodology for finding the center of rotation is correct.

$\textbf{Hint}$ for the second part: Look up rotation matrices. Your image point $ \boldsymbol{r} = (x', y')$ satisfies the linear transformation equation:
$$
\boldsymbol{r} = \boldsymbol{x}_0 + R \boldsymbol{\Delta \boldsymbol{x}}
$$
This is basically a multiplication of a position vector $\Delta\boldsymbol{x}$ by a rotation matrix $R$ followed by a shift by a constant vector $\boldsymbol{x}_0$. You have all the information you need to determine $\boldsymbol{x}_0$, $R$ and $\Delta \boldsymbol{x}$.

Comment: A bit more difficult but fun to think about: it's possible to do it even if you weren't told that it was a $90^\circ$ rotation.

Comment: I found a youtube video that told me to subtract the center point of rotation from the point I want to rotate. Then I flipped the $(x,y)$ and made the new $x$ coordinate negative. Finally, I addd the point of rotation back in and I got (-5,-7). It was the right answer. Now that I think about it, it does seem like the type of operations you usually do with matrices. (I just started learning about them).

Comment: this recipe is correct but you shouldn't do it this way if you don't _understand_ why this sequence of operations gets you to the right point.

Answer (score 1):

Let us call the point of intersection of perpendicular bisectors C$(-3,-4)$, and P$(-6,-2)$.

If we want to rotate P$(-6,-2)$ counterclockwise by 90 with center at C, we can shift P by a distance of PC on the perpendicular to PC at C.

Equation of Perpendicular to PC at C is , $-3x+2y-1=0$, Now tricky part is how to use the distance form , $\dfrac{x-x_1}{\cos\theta}=\dfrac{y-y_1}{\sin\theta}=\pm r$. If the slope of line is + then if we go toward +y i.e. +r we will actually be shifting the point clockwise so will use the distance  -r.

$\dfrac{x+3}{\cos\theta}=\dfrac{y+4}{\sin\theta}=- r$

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do this without matrices, using only the elementary tools you used so far:

Let's say that O is the center of rotation, X is the point you want to rotate, and Y is the point it rotates to. Since this is a 90 degrees rotation, the angle between lines OX and OY should be 90 degrees. You know the coordinates of O and X, so you can find the equation of the line OX, and then the equation of the line that is perpendicular to OX at O. Knowing the equation of this line, you can now find the point Y on it that has the particular distance from O equal to OX (which you can also calculate). You will find two possible points Y, of which one will correspond to clockwise and the other to counterclockwise rotation.